# Create alias with `>& /dev/null &` for GUI apps

Tags: command-line, gui, alias

Every time I run audacious from terminal, I have to type this: `audacious my_song.mp3 >& /dev/null &`

Is there an alias for this, so that if I only type `audacious my_song.mp3` it will become `audacious my_song.mp3 >& /dev/null &`.

P/S: `&` is to make `audacious` run in background and `>& /dev/null` is to ignore some infomation from stdout and stderr.

---

My short answer:

```
$ cd # to go to home directory
$ # make directory where you save your aliases
$ mkdir alias.d && cd alias.d
$ cat << EOF > audacious.sh
#!/bin/bash
audacious "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
EOF
$ chmod u+x audacious.sh
$ cd # to go to home directory
$ echo "alias audacious='~/alias.d/audacious.sh'" >> .bash_aliases
$ source .bash_aliases # make sure your .bashrc source .bash_aliases
```

Comment: Since you have to pass arguments to `audacious`, which must be done before the `&`, you have to use functions instead.

Comment: Also , you have odd syntax there, use `&>` or `2>&1 > /dev/null  ` instead of `>&`

Comment: Thanks so much, now I have `foo () { /usr/bin/audacious "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 & }`